# How to export a list of intersections of 2 datasets of boundries/polygons

Tags: postgis, carto, boundaries

I am using the following datasets:

- NYC Zip Codes: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Business/Zip-Code-Boundaries/i8iw-xf4u
- NYC City Council Districts: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/City-Council-Districts/yusd-j4xi/data

I want to generate 2 lists, the zip codes in or partially in each council district, and the council districts in or partially in each zip code.

So far I have tried this in Carto but I am open to other solutions.

I have found examples of intersecting a second layer of data with points, but nothing about intersecting 2 layers of data where both data sets are boundaries.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a SQL query similar to this one:

```
SELECT 
   d.coun_dist as district,  --- z.zipcode as zipcode
   array_agg(z.zipcode) as zipcodes --- array_agg(d.coun_dist) as districts
FROM 
  nyc_zipcodes z, nyc_districts d
WHERE 
  st_intersects(z.the_geom, d.the_geom)
GROUP BY 1
```

Result:

```
| district |                         zipcodes                   |
|----------|:--------------------------------------------------:|
|    48    |  ["11229","11235","11224","11210","11230","11223"] |
|    18    |  ["10460","10472","10473","10474","10462","10461"] |
|    ...   |                         ...                        |
```

Do not forget to replace `nyc_zipcodes` and `nyc_districts` with your dataset names. Also notice that you will need to run the query twice, replacing the columns selected with the code after the comments `---`. You can learn more about [PostGIS `ST_Intersects` operation](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html) and [PostgreSQL `array_agg` method](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) reading their documentation.